# Determining the number of possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> How many passwords of 3 distinct digits are possible?

$$10P3=720$$

> A 5-member team is formed by two coaches and three players. If in total there are 10 coaches and 15 players, what is the total number of possible teams to be formed.

$$10\times9\times15\times14\times13=245700$$

Do you see any mistake?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @XanderHenderson the questions aren't that cumbersome, that's why I decided to merge them into one post.
I don't understand why you are voting for the post to be closed after I have accepted an answer.

Comment: Your question does not meet the standards of the site.  You have asked multiple questions in one post.  The question you have asked is also incredibly local---it is unlikely to be of much use to any future user of the site.  Remember that the goal of MSE is to create a searchable database of question and answer pairs which are likely to be helpful for future readers.  MSE is not a tutoring service, nor a homework checking service.

Comment: Finally, your question is almost certainly already answered on the site---if you look at the sidebar on the right, there are many "related" questions, several of which are very similar to the question you are asking (same ideas, different numbers).  You could also search the website for other examples.  For many reasons, your question is not appropriate for MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second question is one of combinations, not of permutations. In particular, when you pick two coaches out of $10$, you pick a *combination* , not a permutation of the coaches (because once the team is picked, we don't look at the order in which people were picked, but only if they were in the team or not). Therefore, the answer is $^{10}C_2 \times ^{15}C_3$, and *NOT* $^{10}P_2 \times ^{15}P_3$ which is your answer $245700$.

The first is one of permutations, so your answer is right.

Comment: Right.. I didn't pay attention. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

However for the second one, the order each member is picked does not matter. We can pick Paul as the first coach and Rody as the second coach, and that's the same as picking Rody then Paul. For contrast, in the first problem the password 123 is different from 213 since the order makes these two permutations distinct.

So for the second one, the answer is $\binom{10}{2} \times \binom{15}{3} = \frac{10 * 9}{2 * 1} * \frac{15 * 14 * 13}{3 * 2 * 1}$.

This can also be thought of as choosing the two coaches $10 * 9$ ways, then since there are $2$ ways to reorder them, we divide by two since otherwise we double-count. Likewise we have $3 * 2 * 1$ ways to reorder the three players we choose.

Note: $\binom{a}{b}$ is notation for "$a$ choose $b$". It can also be written $ _aC_b$, and is equal to $\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very clear!